# Problem when using recursive_directory_iterator()

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-filesystem

Why when I try to iterate all directories and subdirectories of a partition using recursive_directory_iterator() from Boost, when it reaches the end, Visual Studio 2010 gives me an Abort error ?

```
path Path = "e:\\";
for(recursive_directory_iterator it(Path); it != recursive_directory_iterator(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Boost are you using?  There was a bug related to empty directories until 1.35:
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1061

Is your directory (sometimes) empty?

Comment: I am using 1.44 yes, I have a empty directory, but it iterates after that, but when it end, it gives me the error

Comment: Try it with a non-empty directory, just for fun.  Does it then make it through 100% of the files within, or does it crash somewhere midway, or does it work then?